# Python ciscoconfparse to find shutdown interfaces and the whole interface block?

Tags: python-3.x, cisco, cisco-ios, ciscoconfparse

The following examples will use this configuration which is taken from http://pennington.net/tutorial/ciscoconfparse/ccp_tutorial.html#slide3

```
! filename:exampleswitch.conf
!
hostname ExampleSwitch
!
interface GigabitEthernet 1/1
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet 1/2
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport nonegotiate
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet 1/3
 no switchport
 ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

This is the code which is also taken from  http://pennington.net/tutorial/ciscoconfparse/ccp_tutorial.html#slide7

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

parse = CiscoConfParse('exampleswitch.conf', syntax='ios')

for intf_obj in parse.find_objects_w_child('^interface', '^\s+shutdown'):
    print("Shutdown: " + intf_obj.text)
```

Output

```
$ python script.py 
Shutdown: interface GigabitEthernet 1/1
$
```

The code is working just fine. But instead of just displaying `Shutdown: interface GigabitEthernet 1/1`, would it be possible to display the whole `interface GigabitEthernet 1/1` block in the output which is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet 1/1
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is **find_blocks**.

> **find_blocks**(linespec, exactmatch=False, ignore_ws=False).
> Find all siblings matching the linespec, then find all parents of those
> siblings. Return    a list of config lines sorted by line number,
> lowest first

Have a look at the [Ciscoconfparse API Documentation](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/api_CiscoConfParse.html#ciscoconfparse.CiscoConfParse.find_blocks) which includes an Example.

So I guess it would look something like this:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

parse = CiscoConfParse('exampleswitch.conf', syntax='ios')

for intf_obj in parse.find_blocks(r'^\sshutdown'):
      print(intf_obj)
```